# UI effects are gone in chosen multi select box

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

We use a multi select box in our application using Chosen Jquery plugin. When we click on a button to show the select box, it lists all the options. However, the issue is these options are not listed in a way as it should be shown by the plugin.

All the values are listed but there is no text box showing up to enter a text to filter values from the long list. See attached screenshot. Basic select box functionality seems to be working (like selecting multiple values and submitting) but the UI effects are also gone.

Internet Explorer 8 is the standard browser in our organization. When we try it on other browsers like Chrome/Firefox, the select box seems to be working fine without any issues. But it stopped working in IE 8.

This has been working for more than a year without any issues and suddenly it stopped working. We didn’t make any code changes to this section of the application in the last one year.

I’ve copied the code below for your reference. I’m sure the same code below was working fine more than a year in IE 8.

```
$(".AssignAccount,.AssignCust,.AssignRegion").live("click", function(){
    $(".modal-backdrop").show();
    var modal = $("#modalBox"); 
    $(".modalBox").animate({
                'top': '10%',
                'left': calcModPos() + 'px'
            }, 300);
    $("#contentdiv").height(300);       
    $(".chzn-container, .chzn-drop").css('width','400px');
    $("#modalBox").show();
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we go..

I did some more research myself and found what went wrong. There was a security patch applied on all our PCs last week and it disabled the security settings on IE browsers. We had to add the application URL to the safe websites list (we never had to do that before). Once we added the link to safe websites list in IE 8, things started working again. All 400+ users in our organization experienced the same issue and after the link was added to safe websites, it started working for all of them.